# Using binding to a List<UserControl> how can I do for not showing the controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is the code which I'm working:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Objective}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="1,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

When set ItemsSource to listBox. It contains:

```
List<Container>
(Below container properties)
    - Objective: string
    - Problems: List<UserControls>
```

Look at this line: `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}" >`
In the code, Problems is a list of UserControls. When I load the program, the listbox is showing the controls from the user control and it's supposed to show the rectangle.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Output-window of Visual Studio and you will see this:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='XXX'

It does not apply the template as the Items can be added directly.

---

What i meant about wrapping your controls is that you create a class which holds a property for the UserControl, e.g.:

```
 Problems : List<ProblemContainer>
```

```
public class ProblemContainer
{
    public UserControl Problem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @OscarFimbres: Yes, because it *can*, the ItemTemplate is ignored. Also it's not a ListBox, a ListBox would **not** show them..

Comment: Sorry for my basic knowledge, but how can I fix it?

Comment: @OscarFimbres: Wrap the `UserControls` in a class for example, that way the ItemsControl will not "see" them.

Comment: @OscarFimbres: It should show the template, don't you see empty rectangles?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3133/discussion-between-oscar-fimbres-and-h-b)

Comment: @OscarFimbres: You should modify a lot of code anyway because your data is not really supposed to hold on to instances of UI-elements such as those UserControls. As i see it the design was rather flawed to begin with (see also [model-view-controler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), a related pattern, if you do not know that)

Comment: I'm still reading about that pattern, is so interesting.. but I guess I understand the concepts.. anyway, will you provide a little of help on this?

Comment: @OscarFimbres: Sorry, i just answer questions (if i feel like it), and preferably with as little of a "tail" as possible. This site is not for support and it is not a forum either, If you have any specific problem, search first and possibly ask a question if nothing comes up, and see if **anyone** can help you.

Comment: I was investigating about the MVC pattern, but I see many examples in internet about MVVM. What do you think.. is better do the patten in MVVM for this case?

Comment: @OscarFimbres: Use MVVM, it's a pattern more specific to WPF.